# Torsors in fpqc and fppf topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles, group-schemes

Let $X$ be scheme over a field $k$.

I've seen two different definitions of torsors

1. Let $G$ be a group scheme over $X$. Let $S$ be faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation over $X$ and there is a $G$ action on $S$. $S$ is a $G$-torsor if $G \times_X S$ isomorphic to $S \times_X S$.
2. Let $G$ be a group scheme over $X$. Let $S$ be faithfully flat and affine scheme over $X$ and there is a $G$ action on $S$. $S$ is a $G$-torsor if $G \times_X S$ isomorphic to $S \times_X S$.

The difference between is that one definition  $S$ is faithfully flat and locally of finite presentation over $X$ and in the other definition locally of finite presentation is replaced with affine.

Are these two definitions of torsors equivalent? If not, are there any example where $S$ is a torsor according to definition 2 but not 1?

Comment: "Affine" is certainly the wrong condition to ask for unless $G$ is itself affine (consider e.g. $G$ an elliptic curve). You also don't want $G \times_X S$ and $S \times_X S$ to just be abstractly isomorphic, you specifically want the map $(g, s) \mapsto (gs, s)$ to be an isomorphism.